# fast insertion in loop -mongodb make Application not responding

Tags: mongodb, qt, qt-creator, mongo-cxx-driver

Iam using qtcreator 5, Database mongodb(**mongocxx**) .
Below code is placed inside a loop ,loop works when there is data available in socket .Data reads fast from socket, when i put mongodb insertion code here it makes builded **application not responding** ,But the data is sending to mongodb without any problem.

Data can be see in Qt creater editor ..only the builded application cannot access (not responding ).

How to fix it????

code part:

```
in header file:
     mongocxx::client& conn1 = get_client();
     mongocxx::database db;
     db = conn1["ASSET_TRACKING"];

in Loop:
         if (k != -1)
                    {
                     // qDebug() << "value found at "<<k ;
    
                     qWarning("Got db conn");
    
                    switch(k)
                    {
                      case 0 :
                      {
                         std::vector<bsoncxx::document::value> documents;
                         documents.push_back(
                         bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{} <<"tag_ID"<< e.toStdString() <<"POSX"<<posx<<"POSY"<<posy<<"POSZ"<<posz<< finalize);
                         db["Tagdemo"].insert_many(documents);
```

Comment: If you are running loop in main QT Thread then you are freezing main qt processing thread. Make sure you run the loop NOT in main thread. See QtConcurrent or QtThread/QtRunable etc to help thread it.

Comment: @Dariusz In my main.c there no loop . only mainwindow thread. In mainwindow.cpp there so many classes connected through signals and slots , in that one of the class i put my thread creation code ,

Comment: In each function place ```qDebug()<<"Ptr : "<<QThread::currentThread()<<" Name  : "<<QThread::currentThread()->objectName();```
In main.cpp after QApplication was created, in ur mongo functions and other places. If you see the same pointer & thread name (name could be empty) but from the pointer, if they are all the same then you are in the main thread and your function blocks Qt application GUI refresh routine as all that happens in the main thread.

Comment: @Dariusz  Problem solved . guys from Qt forum helped. i created a worker thread and connected using signals and slots.

Comment: Thats great, yeh that is what I was trying to guide you to too. Can you post a link to thread so other people can learn ?